# retrieving s3 path from payload inside AWS glue pythonshell job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I have a pythonshell job inside AWS glue that needs to download a file from a s3 path. This s3 path location is a variable so will come to the glue job as a payload in `start_run_job` call like below:

```
import boto3    
payload = {'s3_target_file':s3_TARGET_FILE_PATH,
            's3_test_file': s3_TEST_FILE_PATH}
    job_def = dict(
                JobName=MY_GLUE_PYTHONSHELL_JOB,
                Arguments=payload,
                WorkerType='Standard',
                NumberOfWorkers=2,
            )

response = glue.start_job_run(**job_def)
```

My question is, how do I retrieve those s3 paths from the payload inside AWS Glue pythonshell job that comes through boto3? Is there any sort of handler we need to write similar to AWS Lambda?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [docimentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html). All you need is here.

You can use the `getResolvedOptions` as follows:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['JOB_NAME',
                           'day_partition_key',
                           'hour_partition_key',
                           'day_partition_value',
                           'hour_partition_value'])
print "The day partition key is: ", args['day_partition_key']
print "and the day partition value is: ", args['day_partition_value']
```

Comment: see this new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046474/arguments-error-while-calling-an-aws-glue-pythonshell-job-from-boto3