# arguments error while calling an AWS Glue Pythonshell job from boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

Based on the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044032/retrieving-s3-path-from-payload-inside-aws-glue-pythonshell-job/58044919#58044919), I have an AWS Glue Pythonshell job that needs to retrieve some information from the arguments that are passed to it through a boto3 call.

My Glue job name is `test_metrics`

The Glue pythonshell code looks like below

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['test_metrics',
                           's3_target_path_key',
                           's3_target_path_value'])

print ("Target path key is: ", args['s3_target_path_key'])
print ("Target Path value is: ", args['s3_target_path_value'])
```

The boto3 code that calls this job is below:

```py
glue = boto3.client('glue')

response = glue.start_job_run(
    JobName = 'test_metrics',
    Arguments = {
        '--s3_target_path_key': 's3://my_target',
        '--s3_target_path_value': 's3://my_target_value'
    } 
)

print(response)
```

I see a `200` response after I run the boto3 code in my local machine, but Glue error log tells me:

```
test_metrics.py: error: the following arguments are required: --test_metrics
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which job you are trying to launch? Spark Job or Python shell job?

If spark job, JOB_NAME is mandatory parameter. In Python shell job, it is not needed at all.

So in your python shell job, replace

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['test_metrics',
                           's3_target_path_key',
                           's3_target_path_value'])
```

with

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                           ['s3_target_path_key',
                           's3_target_path_value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html) is kinda broken.

I had to update the boto3 code like below to make it work

```
glue = boto3.client('glue')
response = glue.start_job_run(
               JobName = 'test_metrics',
               Arguments = {
                 '--test_metrics': 'test_metrics',
                 '--s3_target_path_key':   's3://my_target',
                 '--s3_target_path_value':   's3://my_target_value'} )
```

Comment: No, your first argument in the python code will not be `test_metrics`, that should be `JOB_NAME` in the `getResolvedOptions`.

Comment: If I do that, I get this error `error: the following arguments are required: --JOB_NAME`

Comment: I am checking the code, but you may just pass `JOB_NAME`. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/master/awsglue/utils.py

Answer (score -1):

We can get glue job name in python shell from sys.argv